# How to style a image button without the grey default background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I define a Button with this code

```
<ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
         android:src="@drawable/library_blau" />
```

and the result is

[image]

Does someone know how to remove this grey area behind the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change `ImageButton` into `ImageView` or change `android:src` into `android:background`.

Answer (score 1):

set background property of ImageButton instead of src.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
     android:src="@drawable/library_blau"
     android:clickable="true" />
```

or:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
     android:background="@drawable/library_blau" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You add `android:background = "@android:color/transparent"` as backgorund for your image button

```
 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:src="@drawable/library_blau" />
```